# Ember 2: extract model data

Tags: javascript, selenium, ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to extract Model data from existing Ember app (ember version >= 2.10) without any changes in app's sources.

For example I want to have some Selenium test for my UI based on Ember. And some of my initialization code depends on Models in Ember. Can I extract this models via some pretty JS script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `store` from outside its namespace.  Meaning if you dont have access to an Ember `container` you will not be able to look up the `store`.

You would have to modify the source code to do something hacky like setting the main App `store` as a global property (*not recommended as it can lead to memory leaks*) and accessing that global `store` with your test suite.

Recommended: rely on Embers well thought Acceptance tests:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/testing/acceptance/

If you did have access to the `App` instance you could simply:

```
var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main');
var post = this.store.peekRecord('post', 1); // => no network request
```